# Making bash TAB completion more like cmd.exe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, sh

I wondered if theres a way to do rotational style completion in bash similar to the behavoir on cmd.exe, I've found it speeds me up in regard to entering commands

Comment: is there any way of making cmd.exe's behaviour more similar to bash. I make less mistakes in bash because it doesnt pick the wrong file.

Answer (score 13):

In your `~/.inputrc` file, add:

```
"\C-i": menu-complete
```

to re-read that file so it takes effect in the current shell, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>.

Comment: This was really useful for my blind friend. Normal bash tab completion is useless with a screen reader; this makes it useable.

Comment: `reset` would probably work too...

Comment: @Hello71: `reset` affects the terminal, not bash.

Comment: can we make this not case-sensitive as well?

Comment: @KoMet: `bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'` at a prompt or in `~/.bashrc` or `set completion-ignore-case on` in `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: @KoMet: You're welcome. Upvotes are always appreciated.

Comment: works in Terminal on Mac OS Lion too. I've been looking for this for ages. I remember following some really convoluted recipe in Leopard a couple of years go but it never really worked. Glad I checked again - thanks

Answer (score 2):

That won't be a very meaningful answer, but you have answer here:

http://spoonmanwos.blogspot.com/2006/02/bash-completion.html

http://www.jpsdomain.org/linux/linux.html