# How to make Windows tab completion work like on Linux?

Tags: windows, command-line

In the Windows 7 command line, pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> completes to the first matching item (ie, folder or file). In most Linux shells I am aware of, like bash, <kbd>TAB</kbd> completion completes only up to the characters that are unambiguous and then you can either type the remaining character(s) yourself or get a list of completion options.

How can I make the Windows command prompt behave like this as well?

(While searching for this question, I've just discovered in [another superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/222390/making-bash-tab-completion-more-like-cmd-exe) that pressing multiple times the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key will cycle through the options. This is very neat, and perhaps one day I'll actually favor it over the bash-type completion. But for now, my original questions still remains.)

Comment: You can't, but you could download a third-party shell instead of using cmd.exe.

Comment: ... in particular, see http://superuser.com/questions/446271/is-there-a-windows-console-emulator

Comment: mingw includes a bash shell for windows. However, I have trouble with *any* auto copletion in it.

Comment: I have used cygwin terminal for many years, well, I'm very familiar with bat scripts. I even discovered the goto bug in .bat file. I just don't see any advantage of cmd.exe over bash. Umm.. I'm not bashing cmd..

Comment: For the opposite, making Bash tab completion work like Windows, see: http://superuser.com/questions/59175/is-there-a-way-to-make-bash-more-tab-friendly

Answer (score 9):

[clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/) brings some Bash-like features to Windows command interpreter. It's portable and can be injected into `cmd.exe` automatically:

```
clink autorun --install
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH for clink! Why didn't I know it until now?

(Maybe because I was using Cygwin, but it does not work well with `virtualenvwrapper` and now I had to use standard `cmd` ;-))

Answer (score 1):

With Powershell:

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function MenuComplete
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Using `Complete` instead of `MenuComplete` as the function would be a little closer to what the OP is used to.