# Is there a windows console emulator?

Tags: windows, console

Is there any way to make Windows console less ugly? I imagine there might be some 32 bit application that provides a nicer UI, but delegates all calls to cmd under the hood. Is there such an app?

For now, I just want better fonts, ability to copy-paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and other functionality in general, common to all 32 bit apps.

Features like tabs and translucency will be a plus.

Comment: You do realize that `Ctrl-C` is used to abort commands? Do you really want to lose that functionality?

Comment: I found the source code for a program that does it for you http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/216345/add-a-little-color-to-your-console-text

Comment: @DanielBeck, I want to be able copy without having to highlight text. Some other key binding will also do.

Comment: The Windows console (CMD.EXE) _is_ a 32 bit application.

Comment: @DanielBeck, Actually, why not to use `Ctrl-C` when there is **selection present**? Otherwise `Ctrl-C` may provide its default function. :)

Comment: http://www.mingw.org/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try [ConEmu](http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html) - Windows Console Emulator. I'm the author of it.

ConEmu is highly configurable and flexible tool with hundreds of options :) Fonts, Tabs, keboard shortcuts for standard actions and simply macros, Quake style, ANSI support, GUI apps (putty, notepad++) in tabs and much more.

Note. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> by default paste only first line from clipboard. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> paste all lines. This was made to avoid unexpectedly execution of commands on paste in prompt.

And how about to change cursor position in prompt with mouse click?

[image: Window Console Enhancement]

Comment: +1. I am accepting this answer, because that's the least I can do to thank you for this amazing tool. :)

Answer (score 8):

[Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) does everything you ask for, and more. Except you should reconsider the Ctrl-C as Daniel points out. By default, on most OS, copying from a gui console is done simply by highlighting text with the mouse.

Comment: @stijn, Did you try ConEmu?

Comment: @Maximus no, actually first time I hear about it. Will try it if I have some spare time.

Answer (score 4):

You could install CygWin and use Putty with it: https://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/

Answer (score 2):

What about http://code.google.com/p/mintty/?

Nice and slick, based on Putty.