# Open very long name file with terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, shell

Is there is a way to open very long name file from command Prompt in easy way ? rather than

`start fileName.type`

Comment: If you're talking the Windows command prompt, press the TAB button and it'll scroll through the autopopulated fields for you as well. so it you type `start`  the space and then `fil` and then press tab, it'll generate the next closest file or folder name perhaps. I thought you were talking Linux terminal ans not Windows command prompt.

Comment: See here as well [Tab Completion Article 1](http://superuser.com/questions/445677/how-to-make-windows-tab-completion-work-like-on-linux) and [Tab Completion Article 2](http://www.howtogeek.com/195207/use-tab-completion-to-type-commands-faster-on-any-operating-system/)

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE haha i forget to TAB although i know it.. thanx anyway

Comment: @Error : Please specify which shell you are using. If you just tag your question with _shell_, it means POSIX shell, and I don't think that you seriously want to run a POSIX shell in a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Turn on auto-complete in Windows command prompt

> If you are a Windows power user who frequently needs to use the command prompt regularly, then you find it useful to turn on auto-complete in command prompt. If you want to make the change permanent, you will have to edit the Windows Registry.
>
> File name completion and folder name completion are quick-search features of the Windows command processor or cmd.exe. Auto-complete for CMD.exe is not enabled by default in Windows – you have to enable it.
>
> If auto-complete in Windows command prompt with the Tab key is not already enabled by default in the version of Windows that you are using, you can activate auto-complete permanently or for the current session only by following these instructions.
>
> **Activate auto-complete in CMD temporarily**
>
> To activate auto-complete in CMD for the current user for the current command session, open Run box, type `cmd /f` and press Enter. The `/f` switch, enables or disables file and directory name completion characters.
>
> Now press Ctrl+D to complete the folder name or Ctrl+F to complete a file name. Keep pressing this key combination and see the file names change.
>
> To deactivate automatic complete, type `cmd /f:off` .
>
> **Turn on auto-complete in CMD permanently**
>
> To enable auto-complete permanently in command prompt, run `regedit` to open the Registry Editor, and navigate to the following registry key:
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`
>
> You will have to edit the `CompletionChar` value. The default is 40 in Hexadecimal. Set the value of `REG_DWORD` to `9`. This will enable folder name completion.
>
> Next, double-click on `PathCompletionChar` and change its value to `9`.
>
> This will set the Tab key as the control character.
>
> If you want to use the same control characters that you use for a single command session as mentioned in the first part of this post, then set the values as follows:
>
> - 4 for Ctrl+D
> - 6 for Ctrl+F
>
> The file name auto-completion feature will work on folders too, because Windows will search for the complete path and match against both file and folder names.

<sup>**Source:** [Turn on Auto-Complete in Windows Command Prompt](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/autocomplete-in-windows-command-prompt)</sup>

Comment: without using GUI

Comment: I changed the answer so that it uses the Tab key on the keyboard instead of drag and dropping the file/folder icon from the Windows Explorer GUI.

Comment: But why do you have to do this? Autocomplete was already enabled by default. Just press tab